# Is there any way to debug Lightbox2 on Magento 1411

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento-1.4, lightbox2

I'm trying to use Lightbox2 on view.phtml. I have included both "lightbox.js" and "lightbox.css". I'm using jQuery 1.8.2. jQuery is called before "lightbox.js". I can see these files have been included when I take a look at the home page code, I can download "lightbox.js" and "lightbox.css" code.

When I click on lightbox link, it displays the first image in a new page, instead of poping up the image inside of a popup window.

Any clue ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your target set at?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not that good. What do you mean by target ?

Comment: If you have `target="_blank"` on your link, it will open a new window.

Comment: I did not use the tag "target"

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code

```
        <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
        <a class="example-image-link"  visibility: hidden href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a class="example-image-link" visibility: hidden href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a class="example-image-link" visibility: hidden href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Homepage header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/css/styles-th-lpf.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/css/adpopup-pro.min.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/css/lightbox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/js/varien/weee.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/js/jquery.1.8.2.noConflict.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/js/jquery.sliderTE-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/js/adpopup-pro.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.lapetiteflute.com/skin/frontend/interface_lpf_fr/theme_lpf/js/general.js"></script>
```